# How to see application logs while running unit tests in Rider?

Tags: unit-testing, logging, nunit, serilog, rider

I'm using Serilog, NUnit and Rider. I'm running unit tests from Rider Unit Tests window and after test fails I see the result and stacktrace. But I want to see serilog logs of my application to get more information of what going on, how to turn it on?

I tried to add Serilog.Sinks.NUnit but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the NUnit docs of `TestContext.Progress` ([see here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestContext.html#progress)):

> Gets a TextWriter used for sending normal (non-error) output intended for immediate display.

So your logs have to be forwarded to `TestContext.Progress`. Depending on how the logs are created, the approach might vary.

Assuming that you use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` in combination with Serilog, you could create a custom logger like this and use it in your tests:

```cs
public class ImmediateLogger : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger
{
    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        TestContext.Progress.WriteLine($"{logLevel.ToString()}: {formatter(state, exception)}");
    }

    // remaining things left out for brevity
}
```

Comment: I need application logs, not test logs

Comment: That's what I write: you have to forward your application logs

Comment: @mu88 how would I wire up the `ImmediateLogger`?